# Fully responsive items with CSS grid and auto-fit minmax

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

The use of `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(600px, 1fr))` makes it easy to build a responsive CSS grid. The container will be filled with as many elements fit into a row, without using a media query.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the items are wider than the screen when the screen is smaller than the min-value specified in `minmax()`. You can fix this by adding a media query at `400px`, but this only works when you know that there's no content around the container. And that's almost impossible when the container could be placed anywhere.

**Is there a way or property to tell the items that they should never be wider than 100%?**

Something like: Fill the container with as many 400px items as possible, but ensure that non of them gets wider than 100% of the width of the container.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/electerious/pen/gogWLE)

Comment: More about auto-fill and auto-fit: https://blog.jonstodle.com/responsive-layout-with-css-grid-part-2-auto-fit-auto-fill/

Comment: Since there are other elements on the page, your media query would have to be based on the entire layout, not just this one container. So when *all content* on the page squeezes this container down to 400px, then trigger the media query...

Comment: Otherwise, use a script that switches the value of `grid-template-columns` when it detects a width of 400px on the container.

Comment: @Michael_B That's correct. The media query only works when the container fills the whole page. This is usually not the case. A script that implements "element queries" could solve this. Looks like it isn't possible in CSS only :(

Comment: This is not really related to CSS grids, as it's true with any responsive-width element that uses a `min-width`. It would only be possible using [element queries](https://tomhodgins.github.io/element-queries-spec/element-queries.html) (polyfill [here](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries))

Answer (score 3):

You should change `grid-template-columns` to `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 400px))` because `minmax` works this way: it tries to apply max value and if fails it applies minimum. But in this you can get blank space in your grid to the right. Demo:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 400px));
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Fill the container with as many 400px items as possible, but ensure that non of them gets wider than 100% of the width of the container.

For that you can use the "max-content" property, in your example this would be:

```
.unresponsive {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, auto));
    grid-auto-columns: max-content;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but it's not working. I guess it's because there're no implicitly-created grid columns (grid-auto-columns) when the template columns auto-fit/fill. max-content inside the minmax didn't work for me either.